# Regression to the mean with correlated and cumulative past

Tags: probability

My colleagues and I are posing this question to our intro statistics students, but are in disagreement about the answer:

Suppose a student always got scores far above the class average throughout high-school. On her second-to-last mathematics exam she receives a score of 92%, well below her personal average, while the class average on this exam was 76%.

On the one hand, considering only HER scores, regression to the mean may predict a final score above 92%. On the other hand, if there is correlation between the exams, then her score might be lower. Would love to hear thoughts about this.

Comment: You need a model of the data generating process. It sounds like you and your colleagues disagree about the model to assume. FWIW, I would not pose the question to your students given this.

Comment: Agreed. What is in contention is a generating process for the individual student that accounts for skill+luck, or something else. Would be interested in hearing your suggestions for improving the question.

Comment: The situation is underdetermined. There are any number of DGPs that would be consistent w/ it. Until a scenario can be crafted that can only be the result of a single, particular DGP, there will be multiple, mutually inconsistent answers that are equally correct.